# Can I add user ID to the file name in file upload?

Tags: php

I would like to add user ID to file name in file upload. I tried this:

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
$id=mysql_insert_id();
//Abstract File codes
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['abstract']['name']);
$ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
$newname = $id."_Abstract.".$ext;
$target = "application/abstracts/";  $target = $target .$newname;
if (empty($ext)) 
{ $abstract='' ;}
else $abstract=$newname;
```

But I only get 0 for ID.
I can display $name but $id is not working. Is it because I do not have an input for $id on my form? Thank you. I should also mention that the user is filling out an application form (for the first time) and attaching files on the same page. I had the file upload after the application was submitted I don;t think I would have problem call the $id. But since everything is on one page I might be calling an empty $id.

Comment: you have no id because you didn't `mysql_query()` and insert a new record into the db successfully (or at all). id =0 means you got back boolean **FALSE**, which translates to integer 0

Comment: The new record is entered in the database but with a different ID. File upload is on the same page with the form so everything is being submitted at the same time. Do you think because a new record has not been entered yet the file name can't get ID?

Comment: `var_dump($id)`. if it says boolean false, then yes, you haven't inserted anything, or haven't connected to the db yet, or somethin else blew up.

Comment: When I added var_dump($id) I got string(1) " "

Comment: My file upload/input code is on the same page with the application form. So the user is filling out an application for the first time and uploading the files at the same time. I think I am calling an empty $id to add to the file name. I tried many ways but I am not able to fix the problem yet.

Comment: this is because the god of PHP is angry with programmers who still use mysql and not mysqli or pdo